# In Powershell, how do I extract multiple values from XML

Tags: xml, powershell

In this XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0">
<Devices ClientType="Desktop">
<Device HostName="12345-Desktop">
      <Parameter Name="DefaultEnvironment" Value="Test" />      
      <Parameter Name="WorkstationID" Value="T100" />
      <Parameter Name="WorkstationAgency" Value="A" />
      <Parameter Name="ServerIP_Trn" Value="tng.domain.com" />
      <Parameter Name="ServerIP_Stg" Value="stg.domain.com" />
      <Parameter Name="Production" Value="TRUE" />
      <Parameter Name="Training" Value="FALSE" />
      <Parameter Name="Staging" Value="FALSE" />
     </Device>
</Devices>
```

I'm trying to extract the hostname and WorkstationID in a single line. What I would like to see is

```
12345-Desktop   T100
```

This is what i've tried:

```
[xml]$Config = $wc.DownloadString("http://xmlsource/xmlfile.xml")
$device=$Config.Devices.Device

#to get hostname:
$devices.hostname

#To get parameters:
$devices.parameter | select Name, value | where {$_.name -eq 'WorkstationID'}
```

How do combine both outputs in one line like the above? Do I need to use XPath?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track, but you'll need a [*calculated property*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_calculated_properties?view=powershell-5.1) in order to reach into the array:

```
$devices | Select-Object -Property @(
    'HostName'
    @{
        L = 'WorkstationID'
        E = { $PSItem.Parameter.Where{ $PSItem.Name -eq 'WorkstationID' }.Value }
    }
)
```

e: an example using `Where-Object`  instead from comments-

```
$devices | Select-Object -Property @(
    'HostName'
    @{
        L = 'WorkstationID'
        E = { ($_.Parameter | Where-Object Name -eq WorkstationID).Value }
    }
)
```

Comment: Thank you, this seem to work! How does $PSItem work in this scenario?

Comment: @15433 `$PSItem` is just an alias added in v3 for the current pipeline item, aka `$_` as you're already familiar with.

Comment: I see. I've actually tried a similar approach earlier, I just couldn't figure out how to apply the 'where' filter in the expression. I didn't know you can use it the way you did. Thanks again, I will mark your answer as the solution.

Comment: @15433 It is also possible to pipe to `Where-Object` instead of using the `.Where()` _array method_, but it is slower and can be harder to read with more pipe characters.